# Ios 9 Applink and redirect

Tags: ios9, ios-universal-links

I get applink in ios 9. Work fine if I click into a mail with http://www.domain.org/*. But in my emailing campaing the link in email is a link throw mailchimp, then redirect to my website. In this case, ios open safari, and not my app. Any solution for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're having troubles with Universal Links on later versions of iOS. With iOS9.2, URI schemes not the preferred way of opening apps. Universal Linking is the recommended path forward. However, lots of apps and browsers break Universal Links. This includes Gmail, Facebook, and some other apps - many of these rely on internal browsers. If you're doing an email campaign and seeing this redirect behavior in Gmail, this is unfortunately the expected behavior. If you use the native Mail app, Universal Links should work.